# How to efficiently calculate the Manhattan distances between all pairs of points?

Tags: combinatorics, computational-mathematics

Given $N$ pairs of points in the form $(x,y)$.
How can we efficiently calculate the *Manhattan distance* between each 
pair of point?

One way is to simply calculate the distance between each pair of points,
takes $\mathcal{O} (n^2)$ complexity.

Is there any other way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give a **hint**, if we find the one with lowest $x$ coordinate $x_0$. (this can of course be done $O(n)$)

What information would we get if we did $|x-x_0|$ for all other $x$? (It would take $O(n)$ to do this also.)

Comment: Can you  please elaborate a bit more ??

Comment: I can, but it would kind of ruin the fun of discovery.

Comment: Its okay,not getting it !!

Comment: what will be the overall complexity of your approach ??

Comment: I'm a bit at a loss to understand how a computation that is supposed to yield $n \choose 2$ results (the distances) can be done faster than $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @mathreadler  Can you elaborate it, I really tried a lot but cant came up what you are trying to convey !!

Comment: @Ingix it all depends on what you consider an "operation" to be. You can have vector instructions in hardware doing many $a_i-b$ at once. Many modern CPUs have similar ones. If you combine with multicores parallellism you are starting to be able to do up to say $32$ or $64$ per cycle. To even talk about sequential complexity as usually taught would be to mislead the students from this vectorization and parallelism development.

Comment: Of course, if we are talking about optimizing the constant factor, than all of this is important. But your hint seems to imply something better than $O(n^2)$.

Comment: @Ingix : What is important these days is how parallellizable and vectorizable this is. We can easily define vector-operations which you can do $n$ operations in parallel, then in time the complexity will be $O(n)$. Sequential complexity theory is not particularly important for efficiency these days, but if you can parallellize it. This has been true ever since Intel hit the heat-roof for clocking some 15 years ago.

Comment: There is no architecture that can parallize $n$ operations for **any** $n$. I understand that parallelization can lead to speedups, but they are all in the category of constants (which is important enough, of course).

Comment: There exists no application where you need to calculate all-to-all distances for **any** $n$ either. Yes the constant starts becoming more important than sequential complexity these days.

Comment: 2023 :), what do you have here?
* Any more hints?